# Argument of type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Blob, Blob>'

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to map the result of an http request to an Blob but I get the error *Type 'unknown[]' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable): Observable'*.

Here is a sample of my code.

```
public apiRequest(
  param: string
): Observable<Blob> {
  return this.http
    .post(
      '/apiReq' +
      '/param=' +
      param ,
      { responseType: 'blob' }
    )
    .pipe(
      map(res => new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' }))
    );
}
```

If instead map I use tap, everything works fine.

> tap((response: Blob) => {
> return new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' }); })

Where might be the problem?

Comment: Did you try to add a type of your response, the same way you did in the tap operator?

Comment: Yes, but I get the same error..

Comment: How did you import the map operator? From `rxjs/operator`? I also recommend to check what result `new Blob(...)` returns.

Comment: Yes, the map is imported from rxjs/operator.

Comment: You could also try to provide a type for your post method like `return this.http.post<Blob>(...)`.

Comment: can you try to add braces around the returned value like: map(res => (new Blob(...)) or alternatively make curly braces and write a return statement like: map(res => { return new Blob(...) }